# Fastlane plugin app center giving Provided app_name: 'helloworldtest" is not in a valid format

Tags: fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

I am having problem with uploading the ipa in app center using fastlane app center plugin.
When I run `fastlane test_autocreation  --verbose`, I am getting this error:

> Provided app_name: 'helloworldtest" is not in a valid format.Please ensure no special characters or spaces in the app_name.

Here's the lane that is responsible in doing it:

```
 lane :test_autocreation do
      appcenter_upload(
        api_token: "******",
        owner_type: "organization",
        owner_name: "*****",
        app_os: "ios",
        app_name: "helloworldtest",
        ipa: "./build_Dev/helloworldtest.ipa",
        destinations: "*"
      )
    end
```

Is there something that I may have missed?

Comment: what happened to your problem?

Answer (score 4):

The error message might be poorly worded (my bad!), as this could be due a problem in the org name too. Please use the org name as seen in the App Center URL. For example for my test app in org "JP Org", I have to use `owner_name: "JP-Org"`:

```
https://appcenter.ms/orgs/JP-Org/apps/TestOrgApp
```

I hope this helps. If the problem persists, please open an Issue on GitHub.